# Prove that all naturals $n = 2^k j$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If we have a natural $n$, then $n = 2^k j$, where $k$ and $j$ are naturals, and this factorization is unique.  **We add the restriction that $n \ne 0$ and $k \ne 0$ and $j$ is odd in order to make this statement valid.**

Can someone prove this?

Comment: This factorisation is not unique in general. Consider $2 = 2^1\cdot 1 = 2^0\cdot 2$.

Comment: @Abel $0$ is not natural

Comment: You will need "naturals" to include $0$ for odd numbers. But then one of your naturals *is* $0$, which can be written as $2^k j$ in all sorts of ways...

Comment: Need $j$ to be odd

Comment: " no general agreement about whether to include 0 in the set of natural numbers" : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalNumber.html

Comment: If $k$ and $j$ can be $0$ then the fact that all naturals can be writen in such a way is pretty trivial: if $n$ is even then there is a $p\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $n=2p$ and so $k=1$ and $j=p$. Now if $n$ is odd, then you simply say that $k=0$ and $j=n$ (what you could also say for $n$ even by the way).

Comment: @Ruslan : If you exclude $k=0$ and $j=0$ then what you are saying is that $\forall n\in\Bbb{N},\exists p\in\Bbb{N},n=2p$ where $p=2^{k-1}j$. So you are saying that all naturals are even ...

Comment: @Dolma what I say is $0\not\in\mathbb{N}$. It doesn't imply that all naturals are even. It just says that your example with $2^0\cdot 2$ is not good enough.

Answer (score 3):

Start with a number, say $n=792$.

If it's divisible by $2$, divide it by $2$, thus: $792/2 = 396$.

If that's divisible by $2$, divide it by $2$, thus: $392/2=198$.

If that's divisible by $2$, divide it by $2$, thus: $198/2=99$.

You divided by $2$ three times, so $k=3$ and $j=\text{what you got}=99$.

If you'd started with $n=793$, you'd have divided by $2$ zero times, so you'd have $k=0$ and $j=793$.

In other words, this is just mathematical induction.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ Generally, in *any* ring, if $\rm\:c\:$ is a *cancellable* and $\rm\: c^j b = c^kd\,$ then $\rm\,c\nmid b,d\:\Rightarrow\:j = k.\:$ Proof: wlog $\rm\: j\le k\:$ so cancelling $\rm\:c^j\:$ yields $\rm\:b = c^{k-j}d,\:$ so $\rm\:k = j\:$ (else $\rm\:k>j\:\Rightarrow\: c\mid b,\:$ contra hypothesis).

Thus such representations are *unique* if they *exist*; e.g. if $\rm\, 0\ne n\in \Bbb Z\,$ and $\rm\:c \ne 0,\pm1\:$ then we can let $\rm\:c^j\:$ be the highest power of $\rm\:c\:$ that divides $\rm\:n\:$ (which need not exist in general rings).

Note that the proof does *not* use unique factorization or any related strong special properties. Rather, it depends only on cancellation (and that $\rm\,n\ne 0$ is not divisible by all powers of $\rm\:c).$

Comment: @Peter $\rm\ 2\:$ is cancellable in $\,\Bbb N,\:$ i.e. $\rm\:2x = 2y\:\Rightarrow\:x = y.\:$ So $\rm\:2^j x = 2^j y\:\Rightarrow\:x=y\:$ by induction.

Comment: How do you prove $2x=2y\implies x=y$?

Comment: @Peter That depends on what axioms you employ for $\rm\,\Bbb N,\:$ which could be Peano's axioms, or those for a semiring, possibly ordered, etc. Note that the proof of uniqueness of factorization also depends on cancellation (of primes).

Comment: Any of those is fine for me.

Comment: @Peter Wlog $\rm\: x> y\:$ so $\rm\: 2x\!=\!2y\:\Rightarrow\: 0 = 2x\!-\!2y = 2(x\!-\!y),\:$ so $\rm\:x\!-\!y = 0.\ \:$

Comment: Thanks. I *only* asked for that since although I appreciate most of your answers, it is sometimes better to just explain the "special case" to the OP - in this case $2x=2y\implies 0=2x-2y=2(x-y)\implies x-y=0$ - which is much more simple and then write out  the general idea which the OP might be alien to, but which other users might appreciate a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If in $n = 2^i j$ you take $n \ne 0$ and $j$ odd, then this is nothing more than the fundamental theorem of arithmetic: Each $n$ can be factored into primers (2 is prime) in essentially one way only.

Answer (score 2):

In this answer I will always use the convention $0\in\mathbb{N}$.

Assume that for every $n<N$, $n=2^k(2j+1)$ for some $k,j\in\mathbb{N}$.
Then either $N$ is odd and hence $N=2^0(2j+1)$ for some $j\in\mathbb{N}$ or $N$ is even and hence $N=2n$ for some $n<N$. Since $n=2^k(2j+1)$ we then have $N = 2n = 2^{k+1}(2j+1)$.

Thus, since $1=2^0\cdot 1$ we may conclude by induction that $n=2^k\cdot(2j+1)$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

For uniqueness consider $2^k(2j+1) = 2^a(2b+1)$ and assume without loss of generality that $k\leq a$.
Then $2j+1 = 2^{a-k}(2b+1)$ and since the left hand side is odd we have $k=a$ and thus j=b follows as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: $k$ should **also** include $0$, if it doesn't all the odd naturals, can't be expressed in your form.

$2k+1=2^0 \cdot (2k+1) $, if you don't include $0$, you can only express only ($\mathbb{N}$-odd).

Comment: I remember I used to have a teacher who used the $2\Bbb{N}$ notation for what you are calling $\Bbb{N}$-odd. Is there a general agreement on such a notation or is it just user dependent ?

Comment: Yeah. I **guess** to be user dependent. (Given that you've defined it). $2 \mathbb{N}$ is a right way.

Comment: Well yes if you see it that way. What I was actually wondering was whether there is one commonly used notation which might be preferred (for publishing for instance) ;)

Comment: You can use your own notation with the standard definition given to it.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume $0\in\mathbb{N}$.

Define $ord_2 : \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ as $ord_2(a)$ is the highest power of $2$ that divides $a$. Since $a$ is a number $ord_2(a)$ will be finite and well-defined. Let $ord_2(a)=k$. You have that $2^k|a$, but by definition $2^{k+1}\nmid a$. Therefore, you can write $a=2^k\cdot n$ from the first conclusion.